# "include.query" in debezium has no effect

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, amazon-rds, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to implement debezium with mysql connector, trying to stream binlog events to kafka. I am able to stream data without any issue, but I am not able to send `query` in the json payload. This is my configuration:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8086/connectors/ -d  '{
  "name": "mysql-db-connector",  
  "config": {  
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",  
    "database.hostname": "abc.rds.amazonaws.com",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "read_user",
    "database.password": "password",
    "database.server.id": "1",  
    "database.server.name": "db1", 
    "snapshot.mode":"schema_only", 
    "snapshot.locking.mode":"none",
    "database.include.list": "db", 
    "include.query": "true",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "table.include.list":"table_name",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.spinny.db"  
  }
}'
```

Currently the `query` part in the payload comes as `null`.
I am configuring to run debezium on a read replica, the read replica has `binlog_rows_query_log_events` set to ON.

P.S. With this setting I ran a update directly via mysql, I was able to get the query which updated the row, but when updated via django, it again came as `null`

Comment: Are you sure the records you're seeing aren't snapshot events? From docs - _Query will not be present for events generated from the snapshot process_

Comment: Yes, I am sure the messages I am seeing are not snapshot events, these are new changes only.